# jquery fade out and remove LI element

Tags: jquery

I have a list and there is delete button on each LI element. 
When click delete button, remove LI element with fade-out effect.

This is my code below.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-icon="false" class="recentList">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="showDetail"> 
            <h2>  
                <p class="txtName">
                    Title 
                </p>  
            </h2>  
        </a> 
        <p class="expand">                
            Details
        </p>
        <button class="delete" data-inline="true">Delete</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="showDetail"> 
            <h2>  
                <p class="txtName">
                    Title 
                </p>  
            </h2>  
        </a> 
        <p class="expand">                
            Details
        </p>
        <button class="delete" data-inline="true">Delete</button>
    </li>
</ul>



<script>
$(".recentList").on('click', '.delete', function () {
                $(this).fadeOut(300, function(){ 
                $(this).parent().remove(); 
                });
        });
</script>
```

The problem is when I click delete button, LI element doesn't get fade-out effect.

How do I have to fix it ?

here is DEMO - http://fiddle.jshell.net/5zDVQ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually trying to fade out the `button`, but your objective is to fade out the parent `li` right.? so you have to use `closest` initially instead of using `$(this)`

Try,

```
    $(".recentList").on('click', '.delete', function () {
            var cache = $(this).closest('li');
            cache.fadeOut(300, function(){ 
               cache.remove(); 
            });
    });
```

### [DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/5zDVQ/1/)

Comment: @user3400080 Glad to help..!Q

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fadeOut()` instead of `remove()`

```
$(".recentList").on('click', '.delete', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(300, function () {
        $(this).parent().fadeOut();
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/5zDVQ/3/)**

Comment: That will hide the element, not remove it, the user said remove the item.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
 $(".recentList").on('click', '.delete', function () {
     $(this).parent().fadeOut(300);
 });
```

Basically instead of fading out individually, you just `fadeOut` the parent

**[fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/5zDVQ/2/)**

Comment: Good, but it just changes the visibility to hidden, and does not remove the element from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

here given time to fadeout in milliseconds, to observe the animation you should increase a bit.

Also you giving effect to button and removing parent, effect is more visible it you apply on Parent element.

[Here is Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/5zDVQ/4/)

```
 $(".recentList").on('click', '.delete', function () {
     $(this).parent().fadeOut(1000, function () {
         $(this).remove();
     });
 });
```